# Supabase onAuthStateChanged - how to make sure that currentUser is loaded when reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, supabase, supabase-database

I'am writing a website in React.js using Supabase backend. I encountered the problem with authentication and retrieving data from current session.

My entire app is wrapped by AuthContext. When I change some code and React automatically refreshes the changes, everyting works fine. The problem is when I actually want to reload page (F5), then function getUserId gets parameter (email) which is UNDEFINED. I had the same problem in some components where I wanted to retrieve some data from database basing on currentUser.email...

My question is: **How can I make sure that currentUser gets loaded before retrieving data?**
Found some info about Promise / async / await but couldn't get through it.
I am beginner.

What I have there is:

**states holding currentUser (from auth), userId (from database)**

```
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(true)
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState('')
```

**useEffect dettecting auth state changes:**

```
useEffect(() => {
        setIsUserLoading(true)
        auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
            try {
                console.log(event, session)
                setCurrentUser(session?.user)
                console.log('mail', currentUser.email)

            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
            if (session?.user) {
                //want to get & set user id here! (code below)
                getUserId(currentUser?.email)
            }
        })
        setIsUserLoading(false)
    }, []

    )
```

**function getUserId(email) to read userId from database and assign it to state**

```
async function getUserId(email) {
        try {
            const { data, error } = await supabase
                .from('Users')
                .select('uuid')
                .like('e-mail', email)

            if (error) throw (error)

            if (data != null) {
                console.log('getUserId', "User ID retrieved successfully")
                setUserId(data[0].uuid)
            }
            else if (data == null) {
                console.log('getUserId', "Not able to load User ID")
            }
            else {
                console.log('getUserId', "Different error")
            }

        } catch (error) {
            console.log('getUserId catch', error)
        }

    }
```

I tried doing some [loadingState, setLoadingState] and putting setLoadingState(false) before and (true) after auth.onAuthStateChanged but it didn't work because it is async I guess